# Prove relationship among sides of 30-60-90 triangle only with median to hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to prove $BC:AC:BA = 1:\sqrt{3}:2$ using this diagram with $CM$ being the median to the hypothenuse $BA$ and without adding any more lines?

[image]

I tried to show that $\Delta BCM$ is equilateral which would yield $BC:BA = 1:2$ and by Pythagoras theorem $BC:AC:BA = 1:\sqrt{3}:2$
To show $\Delta BCM$ is equilateral I tried showing angles $x = m = 60$ so I came up with these equations utilizing the constant sum of angles in a triangle and exterior angles:

[image]

But I think this doesn't get me far.

BTW: This problem is being asked in *AoPS - Volume 1: The Basics* in order to derive values for $\sin$ and $\cos$ for 30° and 60°:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What are the theorems you can use? Please note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and are soon closed.

Comment: "Without adding any more lines" is pretty vague. I can, for instance, imagine lines without adding them to the figure. And it's not really that simple to tell whether an intermediate statement is "obvious" enough to state without proof, or actually _requires_ "adding any more lines", or neither.

Comment: Also, are you sure that those ratios are correct? Note that $AB$ is the longest side, and it correspond to $\sqrt 3$, which is smaller than $2$.You shoud have $BC:AC:AB=1:\sqrt 3:2$

Answer (score 2):

I may have found an answer myself: Knowing that the median to the hypotenuse of a right triangle is half the hypotenuse, we can immediately conclude $\Delta BCM$ is equilateral and thus deriving the ratio of the sides like @Prem did.
Showing this fact involves drawing the circumcircle of $\Delta BCA$:
[image: Diagram]
Since $\angle C$ must be right, it needs to cut off a $180°$ arc implying $BA$ is a diameter of the circumcircle and M being its midpoint. Hence $MC, MB, MA$ are all radii of the circumcircle and thus equal.

Comment: Maybe I was supposed to know this fact and thereby solve this problem without adding any new lines

Comment: [[1]] How do you know that the median will give the Equilateral triangle ? [[2]] How do you know that the CircumCircle has centre at M ? [[3]] Drawing that Circle is against your own requirements.

Comment: The circumcircle has center M since it bisects BA which is a diameter of the circumcircle. Having MC = MB = MA, triangle CMA is isosceles meaning angle n is 30, implying m and x are 60. Therefore, triangle BCM is equilateral, thus 2 BC = BA

Comment: I assume I was supposed to know that the median to the hypotenuse of a right triangle is half the length of the hypotenuse since it's taught before in the book this problem emerges from. Knowing this fact, you can derive the ratio of the sides without adding any new lines.

Comment: @Prem The center of this circumcircle to a right triangle is ALWAYS at the midpoint of its hypotenuse

Comment: That is true , but that is a "higher theorem" , which will be hard to Prove "without Drawing more lines" , which is a requirement in this Question. If we can use "higher theorems" , we might as well use "well-known" trigonometric values "$\sin{30}=XX$" & "$\cos{30}=YY$" to get the ratios. @Goku

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use coordinates. Assume $x$ axis is along $CA$ and $y$ axis is along $CB$. Then the coordinates of the corners are $C=(0,0)$, $A=(b,0)$, $B=(0,a)$. The middle of $AB$ is then at $$M=\frac12((b,0)+(0,a))=\left(\frac b2,\frac a2\right)$$
Then $$CM^2=\frac {b^2}4+\frac{a^2}4=MB^2=\frac {c^2}4$$
This means that $\triangle CMB$ is isosceles. Since $\angle CBM=\angle CBA=60^\circ$, the triangle is equilateral. Therefore $$a=\frac c2$$ Using Pythagoras, $$a^2+b^2=c^2\\b=c^2-a^2=(2a)^2-a^2=3a^2$$
So $a:b:c=1:\sqrt 3:2$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**What this Picture is trying to tell :**

---- We are given right-angle triangle $ABC$ with $90^0-60^0-30^0$.
---- Draw a line from the right-angle at $60^0$ to meet the hypotenuse $AB$ at $M$.

**Nothing more , nothing less !!**

This is what we get :
[image: 306090]

In triangle $CBM$ : $CBM = 60^0$ , $BCM = 60^0$ , hence $CMB = 60^0$ , all sides are $a$.

Also $CM=AM$ , hence hypotenuse is $2a$.

This is what we know now :
[image: DONE]

Pythagoras tells us that $a^2+b^2 = (2a)^2$.

Now we eliminate $b$ & get the ratios.

$b^2 = 4a^2-a^2 = 3a^2$
$b = \sqrt{3}a$

The sides are $a,2a,\sqrt{3}a$.
The sides are in the ratio $1,2,\sqrt{3}$.

**No new lines Drawn !**

Comment: There is a missing step in your proof: why is $\angle BCM=60^\circ$?

Comment: We have drawn that line at that angle. @Andrei

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice you went the other way around. I thought you started with $M$ as the midpoint. That's what the original problem states. So you "added" a new $M$, which just "happens" to be the same as the old one.

Comment: Yes , Proving that the midPoint gives 60-30 will take more lines to be Drawn , where-as , we can start with the triangle , Draw the 60 line ( getting the given Image ) , get top Equilateral triangle & bottom isosceles triangle & Pythagoras : DONE. @Andrei